# Sort Flex MobileGridColumn Numerically

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting, apache-flex, mobile, flex-spark

I am trying to use the new Apache Flex [MobileGridColumn](https://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/supportClasses/MobileGridColumn.html) to sort my mobile grid numerically.   The problem is it doesn't implement the sortCompareFunction.

How can I sort this numerically?  Can I change the [source](https://apache.googlesource.com/flex-sdk/+/OK_commit_donation/frameworks/projects/experimental_mobile/src/spark/components/supportClasses/MobileGridColumn.as) and recompile?

Comment: `MobileGrid.dataProvider` can be sorted numerically - if you assign `ArrayCollection` to it

Comment: Is there a way to implement a compare function or do I have to override grid header clicks?  I'd love to have the built in header functionality.

Comment: I don't think that a click handler is needed. Assign your data to `ArrayCollection`, implement sorting for the `ArrayCollection`, assign it to `MobileGrid.dataProvider` and set the `MobileGrid.sortableColumns`.